# Removing Duplicate User Meta

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a standard WP_Usermeta table... that has been duplicating my users info. I have fixed it from continuing to do that but I now need the cleanup operation.

For the uninitiated, they are organized into the following columns:

```
umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

My duplicate rows will look something like:

```
2777, 1088#, billing_city, san diego
2778, 1088#, billing_city, san diego
2897, 1088#, first_name, Joe
2898, 1088#, first_name, Joe
```

How can I write a query to remove the duplicate but keep the first knowing that "DISTINCT" only affects single column values... I am racking my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
delete um
    from WP_Usermeta um join
         (select user_id, meta_key, meta_value, min(umeta_id) as min_umeta_id
          from WP_Usermeta
          group by user_id, meta_key, meta_value
         ) umd
         on umd.user_id = um.user_id and umd.meta_key = um.meta_key and
            umd.meta_value = um.meta_value and um.umeta_id > umd.min_umeta_id;
```

Comment: The table is 500MB, and it is just sitting in SQL pro (running query) will let you know if this works! Thank you!

Comment: It took seven minutes to run but it worked. Thank you so much.